# ¿Puedo usar JSX y TSX en un mismo proyecto y llamarlos unos dentro de otros?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, typescript

Desde hace algunos días comence a utilizar ReactJS, pero en la práctica he notado ciertas cosas que me causan dudas, por lo que les pido de su ayuda.
¿Cual es la diferencia entre JSX y TSX?
¿Puedo utilizar ambas extensiones en un mismo proyecto?
En caso de sí ¿Puedo utilizar las funciones definidas en un JSX dentro de un TSX y viceversa?

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Buena pregunta!

Answer (score 0):

Aquí la pregunta es?
Estas usando React con Typescript o con Javascript?
El archivo TSX es de Typescript para archivos que tiene definiciones HTML (JSX)

Por otra parte si estas usando JSX es exclusivo de Javascript.

Si puedes usar ambos siempre y cuando tu proyecto tenga como base Typescript y permitas Javascript

Perooo si estas usando tu proyecto con base de Javascript no puedes usar archivos de Typescript